# Cell Identifier not found when running app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, xcode12

I've been working with UITables for a long time, and recently updated from Xcode 11.7 to Xcode 12.

I created a new table and put inside a Cell Prototype, with identifier "cellAutocomplete", but when trying to dequeue the cell at "cellForRowAt", I get the error message:

**
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cellAutocomplete - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
**

Code in cellForRowAt:

```
case tableAddressAutocomplete:
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellAutocomplete", for: indexPath)
      let addressToDisplay = self.listOfAutocompletePredictions?[indexPath.row]
      cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Graphik-Regular", size: 15.0)
      cell.textLabel?.text = addressToDisplay?.attributedFullText.string
      return cell
```

The cell identifier does exist in the Storyboard and is entered in the respective field "identifier" at the IB, but this is the first time something like this happens.

I've even copied the identifier from the Inspector right into the code but I always get the same error.

Has something changed in Xcode 12 thus causing the error or what could be wrong? I actually use the same idea on another VC but that was when working with Xcode11.7 (and that VC is still working).

[VC structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4i7e.png)

[Identifier in cell properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7bae.png)

Comment: But is this `tableView` the same as the table view in the storyboard that has that cell? You say "I created a new table", this suggests that this table view controller already has a _different_ table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an IBOutlet could be referencing incorrectly somewhere or your `tableview` is referencing the incorrect tableview in your VC (if you have multiple tableviews)

1. In SearchListVC storyboard, Remove the IBOutlet for `TableAutoComplete F...`
2. re-add the outlet
3. ensure you are setting the correct the `TableAutoComplete F...` delegate and datasource to self in viewDidLoad or in storyboard
4. ensure the `tableview` in the delegate method is actually referencing the `TableAutoComplete F...` tableview
5. Clean Project